# Insert many lists into mysql with python

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

How could I insert 03 lists in a MySQL table in one go.
I have learnt at stackflow (AER)this: (works fine)

```
for x in list_1:
curs.execute("INSERT INTO my_table(column_1) VALUES(%s)", (x,))
```

But when I try this:

```
for x,y,z in (list_1,list_2,list_3):
curs.execute("INSERT INTO my_table(column_1,column_2,column_3) VALUES(%s,%s,%s)", (x,y,z,))
```

I have got many values to unpack, `max.(2)`

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you're iterating through several lists at once, use the [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) function as shown below.

```
for x,y,z in zip(list_1,list_2,list_3):
    curs.execute("INSERT INTO my_table(column_1,column_2,column_3) VALUES(%s,%s,%s)", (x,y,z,))
```

That should solve your problem.